# What different between $request->getContent() and file_get_contents('php://input')?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to integrate something to my Laravel project. When i reading the API i got this code

```
 Route::post('/webhook', function(Request $request) {
    $secret = 'somesecretvalue';

    $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $post_data, $secret);
    \Log::info($signature);

    if ($request->header('X-Hub-Signature') == 'sha1='.$signature) {
        \Log::info(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
    }
});
```

my question is only, what the different between `$request->getContent()` and `file_get_contents('php://input')` ? thank you.

Comment: None, [`getContent`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1470), internally, reads from `php://input`.

Comment: getContent is more flexible.  See the source https://src.hotexamples.com/method/symfony.component.httpfoundation/Request/getContent/-